# How to rewrite a URL in nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-config

I am trying to rewrite the URL using Nginx and below are the input and expected output.

Input: http://localhost/test/studentinfo/DocumentViewer?studentName=ABC&age=25&SchoolName=TREDS&city=HYD

Expected output: http://localhost/student?studentName=ABC&city=HYD

So whenever I try to rewrite the URL, I get the entire parameter URL behind my actual replaced URL as shown below.

My Rewrite logic :

`rewrite ^/test/* /student?studentName=$arg_studentName&city=$arg_city permanent;`

But the output I receive is :
http://localhost/student?studentName=ABC&city=HYDstudentName=ABC&age=25&SchoolName=TREDS&city=HYD.

Any idea on what is the mistake I am making and how to achieve the output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a trailing `?` to prevent `rewrite` from appending the original arguments.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/test/ /student?studentName=$arg_studentName&city=$arg_city? permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Thank you Richard ! It worked now without any issues.